# Ffmpeg input image sequence: can I add arbitrary list of images to that?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

My main goal is making a video out of Blender render files which are PNG files with incremental numeric names. I know I could use `-i %4d.png`, but in a lot of cases of Blender animation, same frames are repeated, so instead of rendering those frames again, it would be much better to reuse the same existing frames. So, I wonder if I tell ffmpeg about that.

For example, let's say that I have 100 images: `0001.png` to `0100.png`. What if I want to create a movie with: `0001.png` to `0030.png`, then two times of `0031.png` to `0060.png`, and then `0061.png` to `0100.png`. Is there any syntax to describe that as the input? Something like (hypothetically)

```
ffmpeg -i 0001.png-0030.png|2:0031.png-0060.png|0061.png-0100.png
```

If there is no such syntax, can I specify just a plain list of input file names in order (all 130 of them)? Like:

```
0001.png
0002.png
0003.png
...
0030.png
0031.png
...
0060.png
0031.png
...
0100.png
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## glob pattern

1. Make copies of the images that you want to repeat:

   ```
   0001.png
   0002.png
   0003.png
   0003b.png
   0003c.png
   0004.png
   ```
2. Then use the glob pattern type for the [image demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1):

   ```
   ffmpeg -framerate 25 -pattern_type glob -i "*.png" -vf format=yuv420p -movflags +faststart output.mp4
   ```

I made the following assumptions:

- You're using Linux or macOS. Windows can't use the glob pattern.
- You want MP4 output.

---

## concat demuxer

Alternative method is to use the concat demuxer which will work on all OS.

1. Make `input.txt` containing:

   ```
   file '0001.png'
   file '0002.png'
   file '0003.png'
   file '0003.png'
   file '0004.png'
   ```
2. Then use the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat):

   ```
   ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -vf format=yuv420p -movflags +faststart output.mp4
   ```

---

#### Also see

- [FFmpeg Wiki: Slideshow](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Windows can't use". I have been using `-i %4d.png` on Windows, and if I understood correctly, it is just creating file copies in order that I want, so why can't Windows do that? But I will choose to use the "concat" option. That looks cleaner than creating copies of the files. Thanks.

Comment: @DamnVegetables `-i %4d.png` is the *sequence pattern* which works on Windows. `-i '*.png'` is the *glob pattern* which does not work on Windows.

Comment: The concat example requires durations to work (as per the [documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow#Concatdemuxer)), which must be multiples of (1/25=)0.04s (they will be rounded otherwise). Without durations, frames get dropped.

Comment: If input.txt contains both JPG and PNG, the output video is corrupted, how I can fix that.