# Ffmpeg, concat input.txt, set frame rate?

Tags: ffmpeg

Damn, ffmpeg's arguments, the documentation, and even the error output are confusing. What I want is assemble the images in the order in "input.txt" into a video file. [Someone told me to use concat demuxer](https://superuser.com/a/1671451/203857) earlier, but how to specify frame rate?

The command that the person gave me was `ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -vf format=yuv420p -movflags +faststart output.mp4`. Since I had been assembling images without `-movflags +faststart`, I omitted those for simpler testing.

I had used full paths for the images, and that somehow caused safety issue. I searched Google and found that I need to add `-safe 0`. So, I tried `ffmpeg -f concat -framerate 30 -safe 0 -i input.txt -vf output.mp4`, but it causes:

> Option framerate not found.

Why are the parameters so complicated? In short, what I want to do is:

- The "input.txt" contains one `file 'full png path'` per line.
- Use "input.txt" as the input.
- Output frame rate is 30
- Output file name is "output.mp4" (video format is mp4)
- Other than above, use default settings

What is the correct ffmpeg argument for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-framerate` option is specific to those input formats which don't store a framerate such as raw streams or image sequences.

In your case, you can retime frames while filtering.

`ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i input.txt -vf "settb=AVTB,setpts=N/30/TB,fps=30" output.mp4`

Comment: What do the things after `setpts` mean? Say, if I want 25, then it is `N/25/TB,fps=25`, and if I want 60, then `N/60/TB,fps=60`?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: I have the same setup as the question but my `input.txt` has different "duration N" directives for different images. Can you think of a simple change in your answer for this scenario or is it worth asking a new question? In the scenario you answered, the `-r` parameter also works, but in my case, no again.

Comment: For different timings per frame, omit the setpts filter..

Comment: !Solved my problem, thank you.